# Paging with CreateDerivedCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I am developing an app that is used to work with 20k + items displayed in WPF listbox, so obviously they need to be splitted into pages.

My current solution is a bit laggy:

I apply a filter using async command with `Paraller.ForEach` on all items and I set `MatchesFilter` property. This works great:

```
 FilteredItems = _allItems.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, x
=> x.MatchesFilter, scheduler: RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler);

_count =FilteredSignatures.CountChanged.StartWith(0).ToProperty(this, x => x.Count);
```

This is fast, keeps the UI responsive and you can see Count changing fast in WPF Label.

When filtering ends, I do (on main thread):

```
Items.Clear();
foreach (var s in FilteredItems.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * temsPerPage).Take(ItemsPerPage))
                        Items.Add(s);
```

And this is where my problem is. Each item is displayed alongside with an image, which is loaded async from a url. The `Clear()` part freezes the UI in noticeable way. I have 250 items per page (it should not be less, because user should be able to search for item based on image with his eye).

Is there any better way to do this? I know about `DynamicData`, but that uses `RxUI 6.x.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DynamicData with RxUI 7.0

Comment: I get error about referencing Reactive.Interfaces 2.5.5. Which version should I use?

Comment: The latest version on 4.x since it's based on Rx 2.x. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicData/4.10.1.1194

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to achieve in pure RxUI?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Data 4 works great with RxUI 6.5 and it's what I use in general. That being said I wanted to just post a code sample of a way to do it with RxUI. Mainly because you don't need to clear and then re-add to update the DerivedList.

```
[TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Reactive")]
    public async Task PagingReactiveUITest()
    {

        ReactiveList<int> SourceList = new ReactiveList<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            SourceList.Add(i);
        }

        Tuple<int, int> pageWindow = new Tuple<int, int>(0, 10);


        //ReactiveComamnd that triggers paging
        ReactiveCommand<Unit> updatePaging =
            ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable<Unit>((_) =>
            {

                pageWindow = new Tuple<int, int>(10, 20);
                return Observable.Return(Unit.Default);
            });


        var PagedList =
            SourceList
            .CreateDerivedCollection(
                x => x,
                filter: (item) => item >= pageWindow.Item1 && item < pageWindow.Item2,
                signalReset: updatePaging);



        Assert.AreEqual(PagedList.First(), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(PagedList.Last(), 9);

        //Trigger Paging
        await updatePaging.ExecuteAsync(null);

        Assert.AreEqual(PagedList.First(), 10);
        Assert.AreEqual(PagedList.Last(), 19);
    }
```

Another note.. If you're planning on doing lots of changes to a list you can also do things like

```
using (SourceList.SuppressChangeNotifications())
{ 
      //DO STUFF
}
```

Which will stop messages from going to the UI until you are done messing with the list

Comment: Your solution would be great if the transform (or filter) function looked like (x, i) => new Tuple<int, Item>(i, x). Then yes, but unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: Well the filter and the Tuple can be anything really. It was more just a contrived example to show you some additional features without having to clear and repopulate the list. You could check for the IndexOf the item on the filter function to see if it's between your Paging Requirements. SuppressChangeNotifications might also be useful for not "Freezing" the UI.... That being said if your source list is rather large I don't think there's anything in RxUI that's going to update the derived list super efficiently compared to DyamicData.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested 20k sample and even with 
DynamicData it way to slow. Now I'm doing manual filtering and inside command with PLINQ and then populating final Items list. I also used SuppressChangeNotifications and UI freezes for shorter time, but it's still noticable. At least now when I change pages or write something in filter box it is usable. Thanks for insights